group by column and get top-3 most frequent values from another column as comma-separated string
There is a dataframe with the columns district, crime_type, date, month
df = spark.createDataFrame(
            [('D1', 'ROBBERY', '2024-02-01', 2),
             ('D1', 'ROBBERY', '2024-02-01', 2),
             ('D1', 'DRUGS', '2024-03-05', 3),
             ('D1', 'FRAUD', '2024-03-05', 3),
             ('D1', 'AUTO THEFT', '2024-01-09',1),                           
             ('D1', 'AUTO THEFT', '2024-01-03', 1),
             ('D2', 'MURDER', '2024-05-04', 5),
             ('D2', 'MURDER', '2024-06-01', 6), 
             ('D2', 'RAPE', '2024-07-02', 7)],
             ['district', 'crime_type', 'date', 'month'])                           

It is necessary to get the list of top 3 most frequent crime_type for each district (as a comma-separated string) and the median (not average!) value of the crime count by month column for this district.
The result should be a new dataframe with three columns: district, top_3_crime_types, median_crimes_monthly:



district
top_3_crime_types
median_crimes_monthly




D1
ROBBERY, AUTO THEFT, DRUGS
2


D2
MURDER, RAPE
1




This method can help you. https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-retrieve-top-n-from-each-group-of-dataframe/

this would work for you
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('D1', 'ROBBERY', '2024-02-01', 2),
     ('D1', 'ROBBERY', '2024-02-01', 2),
     ('D1', 'DRUGS', '2024-03-05', 3),
     ('D1', 'FRAUD', '2024-03-05', 3),
     ('D1', 'AUTO THEFT', '2024-01-09', 1),
     ('D1', 'AUTO THEFT', '2024-01-03', 1),
     ('D2', 'MURDER', '2024-05-04', 5),
     ('D2', 'MURDER', '2024-06-01', 6),
     ('D2', 'RAPE', '2024-07-02', 7)],
    ['district', 'crime_type', 'date', 'month'])

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1 = df.groupBy(["district", "crime_type"]).agg(count("crime_type").alias("crime_type_count"))
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("district").orderBy(col("crime_type_count").desc())
df1 = df1.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(window_spec)).where(col("row_number") <= 3)

df1 = df1.groupBy("district").agg(
    concat_ws(",", collect_list(col("crime_type"))).alias("top_3_crime_types"),
    count(col("crime_type"))
)

df2 = df.groupBy(["district", "month"]).agg(
    count(col("crime_type")).alias("crime_type_count")).groupBy("district").agg(
    median(col("crime_type_count")).alias("median"))

final_df = df1.join(df2, "district").select(["district", "top_3_crime_types", "median"])

final_df.show()


create the df1 where we calculate the top three crimes and concat the crime for each district
create df2 which is the median of crimes for each district
join both the df and select the required columns

